# How to authenticate against GitHub with code without user interaction?

Tags: git, github, libgit2sharp

I am working on a software that has to fetch and pull from various git hosting providers automatically. For GitLab and Azure DevOps I am able to do this silently on a regular basis using username and password or username and a private token.

None of this options seems applicable for GitHub.

The goal is to put the passwords in a secure storage, retrieve them and use them to fetch and pull on a regular period.

All options for GitHub seem to require user interaction.

I am using Libgit2CSharp if it matters. I can also use the git process if needed.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/setting-up-a-github-app/about-creating-github-apps

Comment: I probably should have posted that link as a comment rather than just closing. It isn't a direct duplicate of your answer but might have some suggestions that help you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you!
The article that this one duplicates seems correct as I want to do the remote commands on the command line without user interactions, not to create an app.

I am investigating if the original article is still valid and will update you with comment here.